# Insert a wdFieldDate into a Word (2010) document with VBA

Tags: vba, field, ms-word, word-2010

I am writing some VBA which sets the value of custom document properties in a word document template, updates and unlinks before saving the document to a specific filename.
The document had a date field in it which I require to remain dynamic. To achieve this I am trying to insert the date field into a cell of a table just before I save the document.

The fields.add method requires me to use a range object. The following simply replaces first 10 characters with what I want but not in a table

```
Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=10)
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Add rngDoc, wdFieldDate
```

I assumed the following would work to add the same field to a cell

```
Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Start, End:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.End)       
ActiveDocument.Fields.Add rngDoc, wdFieldDate
```

All I get is run time error 4605 - this command is not available

I think my range is correct as if I try

```
rngDoc.Bold = True
```

The cell is bold.

Any clues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collapsing the range will do the trick for you. See Line 3 of the code.

```
Dim rngDoc As Range
Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range
rngDoc.Collapse wdCollapseStart
ActiveDocument.Fields.Add rngDoc, wdFieldDate, PreserveFormatting:=True
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting your cell range in this way:

```
Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Start, _
                End:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.End)
```

you are trying to overwrite `end cell character` which is not allowed.

All you need to do is to change final `.End` property into either `.Start` to place field at the beggining of your cell

```
Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Start, _
                End:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Start)
```

or `.End -1`, to place your field into whole cell by replacing whole cell content:

```
Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Start, 
                End:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.End - 1)
```